# bcp error when importing data

Tags: sql-server, bcp

**C:>bcp dbo.[item] in 'C:\item.txt' -n -T -S"A-9"**

i am using this command, to copy the data from item.txt file into an item table.
but i get the error as:

**SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 4060
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Cannot open databa
se "dbo" requested by the login. The login failed.
SQLState = 28000, NativeError = 18456
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for u
ser 'A-9\Admin'.**

my host name is A-9. but i am not sure about the username.how do i get it

Answer (score 1):

Add the name of you database before dbo.[item]. `YourDbName.dbo.[item]`

Answer (score 0):

Try delimiting the table switch or adding the -d switch

```
bcp dbo.item in "C:\item.txt" -n -T -S"A-9" -d MyDB

bcp MyDB.dbo.item in "C:\item.txt" -n -T -S"A-9"
```